# postgree group by order by query

Tags: php, html, postgresql-9.1

i have database

```
kode    wilayah        area
001 | Wilayah 1     | Area Padang
002 | Wilayah 2     | Area Bandung
006 | Wilayah 3     | Area Bandung
008 | Wilayah 4     | Area Bogor
004 | Wilayah 5     | Area Jakarta
```

In the table above there is an area for 'Bandung' which is the same with a different code. how to make groupings
area, and when grouping displays the area 'Bandung' with code 006

I made it like this but the postgree error

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_area 
GROUP BY area
ORDER BY kode DESC
```

how to make a result like this

```
kode    wilayah        area
001 | Wilayah 1     | Area Padang
006 | Wilayah 3     | Area Bandung
008 | Wilayah 4     | Area Bogor
004 | Wilayah 5     | Area Jakarta
```

Comment: Why `Area Bandung` need to display `006` and `Wilayah 3`? What is the reason? Are `002` and `Wilayah 2` invalid kode and wilayah for `Area Bandung`?

Comment: Is `kode` a numeric column, or is it text?

Answer (score 0):

I would use conditional aggregation here to turn out the column values you want:

```sql
SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN area = 'Area Bandung' AND kode = '006' OR
                  area <> 'Area Bandung'
             THEN kode END) AS kode,
    MAX(CASE WHEN area = 'Area Bandung' AND kode = '006' OR
                  area <> 'Area Bandung'
             THEN wilayah END) AS wilayah,
     area
FROM tbl_area
GROUP BY
    area;
```

### Demo

Comment: I want to display kode, area, wilayah, with grouping area

Comment: Include the exact output you want in the question.

Comment: thank you, this query is correct, but when I rung on the postgree, there was an error notification, namely failed to find conversion function from unknown to text

Comment: Why did you tag your question with MySQL?  Please edit your sample data and show the _real_ values for `kode`.  Is `kode` a numeric column?

Comment: sorry, I use postgree

Comment: I use varchar in kode

Answer (score 0):

I think it must be
"*column "tbl_area.kode" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function " or tbl_area.wilayah Error*

in that case you can try unique combination of these three fields as you want want one row for each unique "*kcode*" So ambiguity occurs by the db to provide which value.

```
 SELECT distinct on(tbl_area.kode) tbl_area.kode ,tbl_area.area, tbl_area.wilayah FROM tbl_area GROUP BY tbl_area.area, tbl_area.wilayah,tbl_area.kode  ORDER BY tbl_area.kode ASC ;
```

But as per your requirements i am adding the code :
You can add order by.
DISTINCT is used here instead of group by.

```
    SELECT kode,Wilayah,area FROM (
SELECT
  DISTINCT ON (area) area , Wilayah ,kode
FROM
   tbl_area) t
 ORDER BY kode ASC ;




kode wilayah    area
1   Wilayah I   Area Sumatra
2   Wilayah II  Area Jawa dan Kalimantan
4   Wilayah V   Area Sulawesi, Maluku & Papua
8   Wilayah IV  Area Bali, Nusra & Luar Negeri
```

Comment: @HarryWardana you mean , you want to show the last 'kode' instead of first 'kode'?

Comment: yaps , i use postgree an kode (varchar)

Comment: Have you tried my query? And tested for result? You can change order.